# Best practice to activate user accounts of a pre-filled database

Tags: database, user-accounts

I have been thinking on a procedure/method to activate user accounts in pre-filled database. Username and email pre-filled according to existing data.

Since the activation of the account is based on introducing only the user ID (which is know by the user and unique to each) and only clicking "Activate account", my best guess would be sending an URL containing an randomly unique generated activation code to the user mail (which was previously filled in the DB) which redirected to a webpage for choosing a password to the respective user account or automatically sending and e-mail containing a random password to the user's mail.

Is this the best suited method?

Comment: What research have you done as to this being the 'best practice'? Can you include some links in your question, of others who have solved similar problems, and are you following their techniques?

Comment: I guess there are not many informations on this topic based on what I have researched. Normally the mentioned method is probably one of the most commonly used. Are you aware of different techniques? @RyanVincent

Comment: You asked about 'best practise', i suspect what you mean is 'is what i am doing good enough'? The answer is: Yes, it is, as it is commonly used technique! Your comment about the technique you used was 'common industry practise' would be useful in your question for anyone else who searches 'SO' for answers.